# Как построить маршрут яндекс карты API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как можно построить маршрут между двумя точками с предварительной проверкой этих точек на яндекс картах. Нашел пример но там нужно задать точные координаты [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/route-docpage/). А если у меня два input и в которых я ввожу адреса и хочу что бы расчет маршрута был динамическим, то тогда мне нужно что бы маршрут строился после того когда эти поля заполнены оба корректными данными. [Пример валидации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation) помогите объединить эти два примера.

Comment: А почему вам не подходит стандартный контрол для построения маршрутов? Как в этом примере: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control

Comment: @Reni Во первых мне не нужна карта. Во вторых я использую дополнительные поля, например поле с указанием офиса или квартиры. В третьих я на лету хочу на основании данных маршрута считать стоимость доставки. Ну и в довесок все это работает на Yii2)))

Comment: Без показа карты бесплатную версию использовать запрещено условиями. Сценарий доставки тоже сам по себе нарушает пункт условий бесплатной версии.

Comment: @Reni так я использую информацию только для расчёта расстояния. Карту разве обязательно показывать? Мне она как токавая вообще не нужна. Покрайне мере не для этого сценария.

Comment: Да, в вашем описании используются и геокодирование, и построение маршрутов. Сам сценарий нарушает сразу два пункта бесплатного использования - нужно обязательно показывать карту и нельзя использовать бесплатную версию для логистики. Вот полные условия:  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

Answer (score 2):

Маршрут на карте между двумя точками с предварительной проверкой адреса: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/ohs4rnz5/

Строится не совсем динамически, для простоты использовал кнопки "проверить" и "построить".

Использовал примеры https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation и https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator

Согласен с комментатором, по условиям использования это не подходит под бесплатный сценарий.

Кстати, при построении маршрута можно использовать определение местоположения пользователя:

```
control.routePanel.geolocate('from');
```

как в этом примере: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocated_multiroute

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  // Стоимость за километр.
  var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 20,
    // Минимальная стоимость.
    MINIMUM_COST = 500;
  // https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation
  // Подключаем поисковые подсказки к полю ввода.
  var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest1'),
    suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest2'),
    map, routePanelControl,
    addrFrom, addrTo;


  map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.65],
    zoom: 9,
    controls: []
  });
  // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
  routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
    options: {
      // Добавим заголовок панели.
      showHeader: true,
      title: 'Расчёт доставки'
    }
  });
  var zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
    options: {
      size: 'small',
      float: 'none',
      position: {
        bottom: 145,
        right: 10
      }
    }
  });
  // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
  routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
    types: {
      auto: true
    }
  });
  // Неизменяемые точки "откуда" и "куда"
  routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
    fromEnabled: false,
    toEnabled: false
  });

  map.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);


  // При клике по кнопке запускаем верификацию введёных данных и построение маршрута
  $('#button1').bind('click', function(e) {
    geocode('#suggest1');
  });
  $('#button2').bind('click', function(e) {
    geocode('#suggest2');
  });
  $('#button3').bind('click', function(e) {
    if (addrFrom && addrTo) {
      showRoute(addrFrom.getAddressLine(), addrTo.getAddressLine());
    } else {
      $('#notice3').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

  function geocode(ctrl_id) {
    // Забираем запрос из поля ввода.
    var request = $(ctrl_id).val();
    // Геокодируем введённые данные.
    ymaps.geocode(request).then(function(res) {
      var obj = res.geoObjects.get(0),
        error, hint;

      if (obj) {
        // Об оценке точности ответа геокодера можно прочитать тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/reference/precision-docpage/
        switch (obj.properties.get('metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.precision')) {
          case 'exact':
            break;
          case 'number':
          case 'near':
          case 'range':
            error = 'Неточный адрес, требуется уточнение';
            hint = 'Уточните номер дома';
            break;
          case 'street':
            error = 'Неполный адрес, требуется уточнение';
            hint = 'Уточните номер дома';
            break;
          case 'other':
          default:
            error = 'Неточный адрес, требуется уточнение';
            hint = 'Уточните адрес';
        }
      } else {
        error = 'Адрес не найден';
        hint = 'Уточните адрес';
      }

      // Если геокодер возвращает пустой массив или неточный результат, то показываем ошибку.
      if (error) {
        if (ctrl_id == '#suggest1') {
          addrFrom = null
        } else {
          addrTo = null
        }
        showError(ctrl_id, error);
        showMessage(ctrl_id, hint);
      } else {
        if (ctrl_id == '#suggest1') {
          addrFrom = obj
        } else {
          addrTo = obj
        }
        showResult(ctrl_id);
      }
      if (addrFrom && addrTo) {
        $('#notice3').css('display', 'none');
      } else {
        $('#notice3').css('display', 'block');
      }
    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e)
    })

  }

  function showResult(ctrl_id) {
    // Удаляем сообщение об ошибке, если найденный адрес совпадает с поисковым запросом.
    $(ctrl_id).removeClass('input_error');
    $('#notice1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#notice2').css('display', 'none');
    // полный адрес для сообщения под картой.
    if (ctrl_id == '#suggest1') {
      showMessage(ctrl_id, addrFrom.getAddressLine());
    } else {
      showMessage(ctrl_id, addrTo.getAddressLine());
    }
    // Сохраняем укороченный адрес для подписи метки.
    //shortAddress = [obj.getThoroughfare(), obj.getPremiseNumber(), obj.getPremise()].join(' ');
  }

  function showError(ctrl_id, message) {
    $(ctrl_id).addClass('input_error');
    if (ctrl_id == '#suggest1') {
      $('#notice1').text(message);
      $('#notice1').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $('#notice2').text(message);
      $('#notice2').css('display', 'block');
    }

  }


  function showRoute(from, to) {
    // https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator 
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
      from: from,
      to: to
    });
    // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function(route) {
      // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
      route.model.setParams({
        results: 1
      }, true);
      // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
      route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
        var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
        if (activeRoute) {
          // Получим протяженность маршрута.
          var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance");
          // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
          price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
            // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
            balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
              '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
              '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>');
          // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
          route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);
          // Откроем балун.
          activeRoute.balloon.open();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function showMessage(ctrl_id, message) {
    if (ctrl_id == '#suggest1') {
      $('#messageHeader1').html('<b>Пункт отправления:</b>');
      $('#message1').html(message);
    } else {
      $('#messageHeader2').html('<b>Пункт назначения:</b>');
      $('#message2').html(message);
    }
  }

  // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
  function calculate(routeLength) {
    return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
  width: 376px;
  background-color: #f2f2ef;
  padding: 12px;
}

#map {
  height: 376px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0px 12px 18px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

#messageHeader,
#message,
#route,
#header {
  width: 376px;
  margin: 12px 10px 12px 12px;
}

#button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .2em 0.6em;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245) linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1);
  transition: all .218s ease 0s;
  height: 28px;
  width: 74px;
}

#button:hover {
  color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  border: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198);
  background: #f7f7f7 linear-gradient(#f7f7f7, #f1f1f1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#button:active {
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238) linear-gradient(rgb(238, 238, 238), rgb(224, 224, 224));
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}

.input {
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 277px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: .17s linear;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #fdd734;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #fdd734;
}

.input_error,
.input_error:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #f33;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #f33;
}

#notice {
  left: 22px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #f33;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Проверка при вводе адреса доставки</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey="API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <input type="text" id="suggest1" class="input" placeholder="Введите адрес отправления">
      <button type="submit" id="button1">Проверить</button>
      <p id="notice1">Адрес не найден</p>
      <input type="text" id="suggest2" class="input" placeholder="Введите адрес назначения">
      <button type="submit" id="button2">Проверить</button>
      <p id="notice2">Адрес не найден</p>
    </div>
    <div id="route">
      <button type="submit" id="button3">Построить маршрут</button>
      <p id="notice3">Недостаточно данных для построения маршрута</p>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="messageHeader1"></div>
      <div id="message1"></div>
      <div id="messageHeader2"></div>
      <div id="message2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```